# Change method findByOneCss that he received more than one meaning and all

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

This is the method itself

```
private static WebElement findByOneCss (WebElement we, String selector) {
    try {
        return we.findElement (By.cssSelector (selector));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I understand that you need to change to findElement findElements but do not get to take account of all the views.

I have a loop that bypasses the values ​​here he

```
for (WebElement wle: wlElements) {
    WebElement commenWe = findByOneCss (wle, ".activity-new-val");
    wl.setReason1 (commenWe! = null? commenWe.getText (): "");
    wlList.add (wl);
}
```

What does it need to change, I tried to like this

```
List <WebElement> commenWe = findAllByOneCss (wle, ".activity-old-val");
wl.setReason (commenWe! = null? ((WebElement) commenWe) .getText (): "");
wlList.add (wl);
```

But it beats mistake java.util.ArrayList can not be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type `wlList` is you could use: `wlList.addAll(commenWe);`

Or you iterate over commenWe like this:

```
    List<WebElement> commenWe = findAllByOneCss(wle, ".activity-old-val");
    for (WebElement we : commenWe) {
        //whatever [wl] is...
        wl.setReason(we!=null ? ((WebElement) we).getText(): "");
        wlList.add(wl);
    }
```